# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'

Tags: python

I have a Python Script in which I'm opening two files for reading and when I'm trying to close them, it throws me the ***AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close'*** error.

Excerpt of my script is as below :

```
firstFile = open(jobname, 'r').readlines()  
secondFile = open(filename, 'r').readlines()  
{  
    bunch of logic  
}  
firstFile.close()  
secondFile.close()
```

Comment: `readlines()` returns a list, and you can't close lists, only files.

Comment: Do you actually need lists of all of the lines in the files in memory at all?

Comment: Tip for the future: Python error messages tend to be pretty informative if you take them at their word.  If the line `firstFile.close()` produces `'list' object has no attribute 'close'`, then you're trying to get the `close` attribute of a `list`.  That means `firstFile` is a list, not a file object, and you simply have to stick a few `print`s in there to find where in its history it became one.  In this case, that happened immediately.

Answer (score 9):

`firstFile` and `secondFile` do not represent the actual files, they are lists of lines.  To fix this, save the file handles.

```
firstFile = open(jobname, 'r')
firstFileData = firstFile.readlines()  
secondFile = open(filename, 'r')
secondFileData = secondFile.readlines()  

# bunch of logic ...

firstFile.close()  
secondFile.close()
```

Alternatively, you can use the `with` construct:

```
with open(jobname, 'r'), open(filename, 'r') as firstFile, secondFile:
    firstFileData = firstFile.readlines()  
    secondFileData = secondFile.readlines()  

    # bunch of logic...
```

Comment: In Python, `{` are not used to define blocks of code.

Comment: I'm maintaining the same code style that the author used.

Comment: I apologize for using {. I didn't know a better way to represent it

Answer (score 5):

`.readlines()` returns a list. You'll actually want to do something like this:

```
with open(jobname) as first, open(filename) as second:
    first_lines = first.readlines()
    second_lines = second.readlines()
```

the `with` block will automagically take care of closing and cleaning up your file handles.

Also, you *probably* don't actually need readlines, unless you really do want the entire contents of the file in memory. You can iterate directly over the file itself:

```
for line in first:
    #do stuff with line
```

Or if they're the same length:

```
for line_one, line_two in zip(first, second):
    # do things with line_one and line_two
```

Comment: Note that in Python 2, `zip` will read both files into memory to construct the list of pairs.

Answer (score 3):

While other cases are correct, you can also just use the automatic resource management:

```
with open(jobname, 'r') as f:
    first_file_lines = f.readlines()
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    second_file_lines = f.readlines()

# your logic on first_file_lines and second_file_lines here
```

You don't need to keep the files open after you read all the lines either.

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after creating the file object with `open`, you call the `readlines()` method, whose result is then bound to the variable, i.e., `firstfile` is not the file, but a list of strings (the lines from the file) while the reference to the actual file is lost. Same for `secondFile`. Try this instead:

```
firstFile = open(jobname, 'r')
lines = firstFile.readlines()  
...
firstFile.close()
```